# pyinstaller looks into a non-existing python path

Tags: python, pycharm, pyinstaller

I have a file (main.py) in a project that I want to compile into a single .exe file. So I installed pyinstaller through pip on my console (running in the project directory) and it seems to have been installed successfully. However when I type `pyinstaller -w --onefile main.py` into the console, I get:

`Fatal Error: unable to process using '"C:\RepositoryOwnerLocal\venv\scripts\python.exe" "C:\Contributor\PycharmProjects\Project\venv\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe" -w --onefile main.py': The system cannot find the file specified.`

Any help? I am using PyCharm 2022.2.1 with PS console in Windows 10.

Note: I pulled this project from a GitHub repository and I know that the python.exe file that pyinstaller is looking for is a directory from the local of the repository owner. I guess the main question is how can I correct this directory. I have already checked the pyvenv.cfg file and the python directory is the one on my local.

Many thanks.

Comment: maybe try with full path to `main.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try uninstalling and reinstalling pyinstaller through pip.